# Load a file entity by URI

Tags: 8, files, uri

Is there a way to load a file by URI in Drupal 8?

In Drupal 7, it is possible using the following code.

```
$uri = 'public://file.xyz';

// Take a look at: file.inc::file_load_multiple
$files = file_load_multiple(array(), array('uri' => $uri));
$file = reset($files); // If empty, $file will be false, otherwise will contain the required file
```

Taken from here https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2012-06-06/load-a-file-by-uri#comment-6493610

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is the `loadByProperties` method in the `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface` that allows to define required condition in searching the file entity by the given file URI:

```php
/** @var \Drupal\file\FileInterface[] $files */
$files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('file')
  ->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri]);
/** @var \Drupal\file\FileInterface|null $file */
$file = reset($files) ?: NULL;
```

Comment: To exactly match the code example in the original question, add `$file = reset($files);` again.